# Proof of Home Address UK Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk, south-korea

My friend is applying for a UK Visa but she has not proof of address at the country where she is currently residing and it is required for the application process.

She has a tenancy agreement but it's not in her name.

Can this tenancy agreement still be used as proof since she is, in fact, living there or does she need to be the main signatory on the tenancy agreement?

Is there any supporting documentation that can be submitted to make this kind of tenancy agreement valid? Does anyone have any experience with something like this?

Comment: Confirmation of legal residence is required, if your friend is not a national of the country in which she is applying or her right to reside there is not included in her passport. Eg a copy of her residence permit https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, She can use her bank statement, if she has an account in the same country and asks her bank to update her contact address to get an account letter confirming her name and address in the bank letter.

Comment: @Daniel Wardin You welome.

Comment: @DanielWardin: a bank statement is not proof of *legal* residence: if not a national of the country in she is applying, she has to give evidence of her right to reside there, short or long term.. e.g., visa in passport, residency permit.

Comment: @Giorgio Please, read the question, cause the person asked for proof of address at the country and not a proof legal residence. Those are two different subjects. There is a part on the application where they asked to submit tenancy agreement or accountant letter from the bank and other documents to confirm your address and not a legal residence permit.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, I guess I probably misunderstood the original issue but between both of your answers, I'm sure we've got it. She's got a valid Visa so that's perfect.